# How check lambda-expression on bool in ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda

Sorry for stupid question, but i'm newbit in ASP.

I have `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.keywords)` for example.

How could I check for true/false on this expression?

`@if(item.keywords==null)` return null always.
`@if(modelItem=>item.keywords==null)` return error "Can't convert lambda expression to type bool"

Comment: @model IEnumerable<site1.Models.Article> - i have IEnumerable model

Comment: Is keywords a bool variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a collection you can iterate over it with a `foreach`.

Check each property for not null then output it:

```
@foreach(var article in Model) {
    if (article.keywords != null) {
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => article.keywords)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your "Model" var like in this example:

```
@if( Model.keywords == null ) {

}
```

Comment: @model IEnumerable<site1.Models.Article> i have ienumerable model